# Tkinter Aspect Ratio

Tags: python, tkinter, aspect-ratio

How can I keep the aspect ratio of a Tkinter window fixed?  I want my window to
stay square, no matter what its size is. The aspect method seemed
promising, but when I tried the following code, nothing happened.

```
win = Toplevel(master)
win.grid()
win.aspect(1,1,1,1)
```

The aspect could still be changed whenever I resized the window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use it on the main window? i.e.

```
from Tkinter import *
w = Tk()
w.aspect(1,1,1,1)
w.mainloop()
```

Works like a charm for me, running Python 2.7.1.