# Keep aspect ratio upon window resize by user

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As the title says, is there a way to keep the aspect ratio if the user wants to resize a tkinter window? From [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495675/tkinter-aspect-ratio?rq=1) posts on Python 2, I found the following code that apparently did the job, but it doesn't with Python 3.9.5?

```
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()
w.aspect(1,1,1,1)
w.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine for me on OSX. What platform are you running on?

Comment: Windows 10 - I added a screenshot, resizing like this is not possible for you?

Comment: On my machine, with your code I can only resize to a larger or smaller square.

Comment: Strange! Any idea how to obtain the same behavior on Windows?

Comment: Same (unsolved) issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622538/why-does-tkinter-aspect-not-work-in-windows-7